# Deserialise XML with Inheritance

Tags: c#, xml, class, deserialization

I need to deserialise the following XML:

```
<ContactMethods>
    <ContactMethod Method="PhoneContact"> (00) 000 0000 </ContactMethod>
    <ContactMethod Method="WorkContact">  (00) 000 0000 </ContactMethod>
</ContactMethods>
```

Currently, I have a base class called ContactMethod which has fields shared by all contact methods. I also have classes for each type of contact, each of which inherits the ContactMethod base class. I have provided my classes below which has the .

```
public class Applicant
{
  [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArray]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItem(ElementName="Dependant")]
  public List<string> Dependants;

  //CONTACT
  [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItem("PhoneContact", typeof(PhoneContact))]
  public List<ContactMethod> ContactMethods;
}

public class ContactMethod
{
  public string ContactMethodId { get; set; }
  public string Value;
  public Boolean PhoneFacsimile;
  public Boolean PhoneSms;
  public Boolean PhoneVoice { get; set; }
  public Boolean EmailHtml;

  public ContactMethod()
  {
    this.PhoneFacsimile = false;
    this.PhoneSms       = false;
    this.PhoneVoice     = false;
    this.EmailHtml      = false;
  }
}

public class PhoneContact : ContactMethod
{
  public PhoneContact()
  {
    this.ContactMethodId  = "PH";
    this.PhoneVoice       = true;
  }
}

public class WorkContact : ContactMethod
{
  public WorkContact()
  {
    this.ContactMethodId  = "W";
    this.PhoneVoice       = true;
  }
}
```

My aim is to use the constructor for each contact method type to set default values like contact method id's. So how do I map each contact method to the appropriate contactMethod type class using the Method="?" in the XML string.

Comment: Why do you have several booleans for the various types of contact method? Can a contact really be email and phone and sms at the same time? Why do you need subclasses for this, why not just one single contact type with an enum ContactMethod { Phone, Work, Sms, ... } and two fields:  a string for the contact data and a method for the method?

Comment: @Anders Forsgren I'm working with another system which requires these values to be passed in when creating a client.

Comment: Quick and dirty solution: Use a switch statement on the value of "Method", and call the appropriate constructor from there.
Very unsexy, but simple.

Comment: @CodeMonkey from the question it seemed like you were receiving xml *into* your system, not sending it out to another system. Are you doing both?

Comment: @Anders Forsgren My apologies if I was not clear. The system I am working with allows you to develop your custom scripts to implement your own functionality. I am writing a script that accepts an XML string and add add records to the database through this others systems business layer.

Comment: I'd make sure the class that parses the incoming xml is *not* part of a class hierarchy, but uses the simplest implementation possible, and that the items you then pass further *out* of the script are part of a class hierarchy if necessary. That is, separate the concerns of input (from xml) and output (entities to the next system).